# Number of images in a pair of 120 degree mirrors

Tags: reflection

I know the number of images in two mirrors by angle of theta is n=(360/theta)-1 but for 2 mirrors by 120 angle it seems the number of images are 3 instead of 2 by the following picture .would some one help me and say[image] how many images we have ?2 or 3? Or my picture is wrong ?